# Truffle-plugin-verify says passed but still unverified on BSCscan

Tags: truffle, etherscan, verify, contract-verification

Contracts deployed via Truffle are not properly verifying on the mainnet. On my end it says verification passed but on the website it's still unverified. I've been able to deploy and verify the same contract with zero issue before.

With that being said, I was able to verify a simple contract complied with remix and it was verified instantly. Any idea what the issue is caused by?

https://bscscan.com/address/0xE197baBfaa5eE12Cfc36f955f3cce84A4ae3A65B#contracts

When I try to debug the verify it still shows as passed, but is yet to be passed on site.

[image: When I try to debug the verify it still shows as passed, but is yet to be passed on site.]

Answer (score 0):

This was most likely an issue with BscScan at the time, as it can take some time to update newly verified contracts. See also [this issue](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify/issues/74) on the plugin repo where other people had the same problem, but it resolved itself after waiting for some more time. Looking at the contract you linked, it has since then been updated as well.